# New screenshots/files not visible in Finder in Catalina, well visible when using a file manager like Nimble Commander Pro

Tags: finder, screen-capture, catalina

I've set the permissions to the 'screenshots' folder 'read & write' for all users in the list.  The screenshot app is added to have full rights on the drive in the settings...  I don't understand why I can't see the new screenshots via Finder but via any file manager, is not an issue.  Is there someone that can plz let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm Catalina since a few hours only, and this really works on my nerves... :-(. I noticed that I can't see newly added or created files either in the Finder!  If you ask me, this is not really an improvement!

Comment: This is not normal. Is this a third-party screenshot app, or Apple's own? Is the problem that ALL new files don't appear in the Finder, rather than just screenshots? What Mac model?

Comment: It's Apple's own screenshot app. iMac 27" 2017 model.

Comment: So is it all file? Have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes, all files and directories. Rebooted several times.

Comment: @benwiggy I just performed the update to version 10.15.1 (that took longer to install than the OS itself) and after the update, I can see all my files in the Finder!